# Extracting a part of a string up to a number in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have various strings of data that I need to extract up to the first number occurance in the string.  For example, I may have the following:

John Doe12 Somewhere Lane

Basically I need the part of the string up to the number 1 (John Doe), and then I need the rest of the string (12 Somewhere Lane).  The string will not have a space between the name and the street address, so the number of the address will always be right up against the last name.  I don't know if this makes a difference but I figured I'd let it be known.

So is there a way to break the string apart like this using PHP?

Update:

@CMPS recommended the following, which works in the instance below when there is one name:

```
$result = "John Doe12 Somewhere Lane";
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z ]+)(\d.*)/", $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

//************************ RESULTS FOR ABOVE SAMPLE ********************//

Array([0]=> John Doe12 Somewhere Lane [1]=> John Doe [2]=> 12 Somewhere Lane)

For the sample below, it only produces one name after the & sign, producing the same result as above:

```
$result = "Jane Doe & John Doe12 Somewhere Lane";
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z ]+)(\d.*)/", $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

//************************ RESULTS FOR ABOVE SAMPLE ********************//

Array([0]=> John Doe12 Somewhere Lane [1]=> John Doe [2]=> 12 Somewhere Lane)

Comment: Check my post update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH5fH3/1)**

Use regex, here's the pattern:

```
([a-zA-Z ]+)(\d.*)
```

Here's how to use it with PHP:

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/uFE82J)**

```
<?php
$str = "John Doe12 Somewhere Lane";
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z ]+)(\d.*)/", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**Update**

Here's another regex based on your comment:

```
([^0-9]+)(\d.*)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on some samples, but I noticed it doesn't work right on ones like this: John Doe & Jane Doe12 Somewhere Lane.  In this example it only grabs Jane Doe, leaving John Doe nowhere to be found.

Comment: Can you give examples on which examples doesn't work ? @NickThomas